Stuck in circular logic fallacy for Exponents rules.
I tried to understand Bernoulli's inequality for real number. But then, I realized I had to make certain if Exponents rules work on real number or not, especially for irrational numbers. But then I found out they just use approximations for irrational exponents. So my first reaction was that "Oh, if I can confirm whether the exponential functions are continuous, then I might feel relieved using approximations for irrational exponents". But then, many proof for continuity of exponential function or log functions use Bernoulli's inequality. Now I'm stuck. Where should I start?

well I will just cope with the fact that the logarithmic function is defined as the integral of 1/x from 1 to x. Then it would be relatively safe(?) to  use irretional numbers for exponent I guess...
